# duplicate item showing in ui-select list, when dynamically updating new values and changing selected value in ui-select multiple (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

unable to update new values and changing selected values in ui-select dynamically
updated values duplicating inside the list

i have added get employees to update the model and update employee for add new data and preselect that values.

what i have done is

- created a add model button which will populate the values inside the uiselect.
- created a update model button to add the new value and change it as selected

---

- when add model clicked it lists as item1, item2, and item3
- when update model clicked it will add a new item "item4" and make it as selected

**Issue is item4 is getting selected but it is also showing in the list for selection**

---

plunkr link given below
http://plnkr.co/edit/RCEQeSp00QhnLl4wegpz?p=preview

```
 <ui-select style="width: 800px;" ng-disabled="disabled" theme="select2" ng-model="vm.employees.selected" multiple="">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select employee...">{{$item.name}} <{{$item.city}}></ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices refresh-delay="0" refresh="vm.getdata($select.search)" repeat="employee.id as employee in vm.employees | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}  ">
    <div ng-bind-html="employee.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small>
    name: {{employee.name}}
    city:           <span ng-bind-html="''+employee.city | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select> 

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {
var vm = this;
vm.name = 'World';

function getemployee() {
    var employees = [];
    $http.get('employees.json').success(function(data) {

        vm.employees = data;
    });
}

vm.updateemployee = function() {
    console.log(vm.employees);

    vm.selvalues = vm.employees.selected;
    vm.employees.selected = undefined;
    vm.employees.push({
        id: 9,
        name: "test",
        city: "chennai",
        state: "TN"
    });
    vm.selvalues.push(9);
    vm.employees.selected = vm.selvalues;
    console.log(vm.employees);
    console.log(vm.employees.selected);
}

vm.getdata = function(query) {
    console.log(vm.employees);

    console.log(vm.employees.selected);

}

vm.employees = {};
vm.selvalues = [];
vm.employees.selected = [];
vm.employees = [];
vm.getemployee = getemployee;});
```

[plunkr link][1]

http://plnkr.co/edit/RCEQeSp00QhnLl4wegpz?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr link doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like it's working to me.

Comment: @Tj Gienger newly inserted value "test" is selected on clicking update as expected but the issue is, it is also showing inside the dropdown list. Solved the issue by changing push to concat to add new item –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    vm.selvalues= vm.employees.selected;
 vm.employees.selected=undefined;
 vm.employees=vm.employees.concat({id:9,name:"test",city:"chennai",state:"TN"});    
 vm.employees.selected = vm.selvalues.concat(9);
```

Changing push to concat worked for me. **thanks for all who tried to help me**

http://plnkr.co/edit/5za5SpGfXx4z2Jy7AocN?p=preview